# I cannot install my printer

Tags: printing

Hello I just started to use ubuntu.
For the moment I have not a very good impression.
I still try to install my printer and it seems that I need a password for "workgroup".
Can you please let me know how to proceed ? I really need the printer.

Thank you,
Viorel

Comment: Well, you need the password for the workgroup, obviously. Beyond that, we don't have much information, so we really can't help you out very much. If you could add the brand of the printer and what you have tried to so far, that would help us a lot. Thanks!

Comment: also, please describe the work environment, if its a personal printer or if its connected to an office server. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a network printer?
The printing system in ubuntu is called CUPS (common unix printing system).
CUPS has a web management interface that is much more powerful than the little app ubuntu has.
Open up a web browser and type "localhost:631" in the address bar to access it.
You may find it has the settings you need.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on user169254's suggestion.  Go to http://localhost:631/. This is the CUPS 1.7.2 site where you can manually register your printer. When you get to the site, click on the Printers tab; you may very well see your printer listed here, but it may not have been registered automatically. Weather you see it listed or not, click on the Administration tab and enter your printer information. (My printer was listed when I clicked on the Printer tab, and it was also recognized by Ubuntu, but it still would not print because it was not registered automatically.) After you finish entering your printer information, your printer may very well start working properly. Make sure you are booted to Ubuntu and not Windows--if you are, in fact, double booting from the same computer.