# Why can't I add a printer?

Tags: printing

I'm trying to add a printer then suddenly nothing is possible. I don't have a windows workgroup and I don't have a password. What am I doing wrong? This worked before.

[image]

Same problem as in this question [I cannot install my printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400142/i-cannot-install-my-printer) so I'm going to try the CUPS way.

Answer (score 1):

From the gray "`Windows....`" line in the "`Select Device`" window, you seem to have selected "`Windows printer`", which is why you are getting prompted for Windows Workgroup stuff. Cancel these popups, and pick something else.